# Prevent JQuery UI slider handle from starting selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I have a `JQuery UI slider` in my `div`, and I have `onselectstart` set to `return false`, which kills most text selection.

However, you can still grab the `slider handle`, drag it to the end, and then continue down, which starts a selection.  I'm trying to prevent that drag on the slider handle from initating a selection.

I have this code, and I've tried to apply it to the handle without much success.

```
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.disableSelection = function () {
            return this
                .attr('unselectable', 'on')
                .css('user-select', 'none')
                .on('selectstart', false);
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Can anyone give me guidance on how to prevent a drag on the slider handle from being the start of a text selection?

Suffice to say, this does not do it:

```
$("#slider").disableSelection();
```

SUMMARY OF PROBLEM:  Grab slider, drag to bottom of screen.  This starts a text selection from the slider on downward through the page.  It should not.

Comment: If you share your code it's easier to help you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to avoid getting selected? This does not make a lot of sense since most sliders have no text to select.

Comment: No code needed, this is a trivial repro.  Put a slider and some text in a div.  Grab slider handle.  Drag to end of screen.  It selected the text. It should not.

Comment: If you want to disable the slider from sliding you may have a look at the `disable()` method here: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-disable

Comment: That would disable the slider, but then you wouldn't be able to use it...